# Using carousel bootstrap whit ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Im using carousel bootstrap and my images are in cloudinary.
I cant see the images, i can see the buttons next and previus, the text but not the imges.
every idea counts.
Thanks

```
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <% @portfolios_consultoria.each_with_index do |p, index| %>
    <div class="carousel-item <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
      <img class="d-block w-100 url('<%= cl_image_path p.photo.key unless p.photo.key.blank?%>')">
    </div>
    <h3><%= p.name %></h3>
  <% end %>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What did the produced html look like?

Comment: I cant show any hoto because i have a low reputacion yet. I only can see the name of the photo and the buttobs next and previus

Comment: i found the problem I was using img, but i have to use:             <%= cl_image_tag (p.photo.key unless p.photo.key.blank?), class: 'd-block w-300'%>